# Intuitive, elementary intros to Hopf algebras/monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, reference-request, commutative-algebra

**Motivation**:

I'm interested in understanding the role that noncrossing partitions play in Hopf algebras/monoids (HAs) as the components of the power series of the compositional inverse of formal power series (or analytic functions at the origin, cf. OEIS [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264)). The roles in HAs of the associahedra and permutahedra as delineating the combinatorics of compositional and multiplicative inversion are in encoding the antipodes in some HAs. I'm parttcularly interested in unwrapping this statement in Ref. 6 (Varilly et al.):

*Use of partitions with special properties may lead to other incidence algebras: for instance, if we restrict to noncrossing partitions, we obtain a cocommutative Hopf algebra, with the commutative group operation on characters essentially corresponding to Lagrange reversion of the Cauchy product of reverted series [cf. Stanley, Enumerative Comb., Vol. 2].*

**Request**:

To this end, I would like to understand the lingo and constructs of HAs at an elementary, intuitive level and am seeking free pdf papers or books on the Web that discuss HAs at increasing levels of generality with concrete examples.

Some that I'm already aware of are (in roughly increasing generality)

1) "Trees, renormalization, and diffetential equations" by c. Brouder

2) "A very basic introduction to Hopf algebras" by Selig

3) "Coalgebras and Bialgebras in Combinatorics" by
S. A. Joni  G.‐C. Rota

4) "Combinatorial Route to Algebra: The Art of Composition & Decomposition" by [Blasiak](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4685)

5) "Hopf Algebras in General and in Combinatorial Physics: a practical introduction" by [Duchamp](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508337), Blasiak, Horzela, Penson, and Solomon

6) "Faa di Bruno Hopf algebras" by [Figueroa](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508337), Gracia-Bondia and Varilly

7) "Combinatorial Hopf algebras in quantum field theory I" by [Figueroa](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408145) and Gracia-Bondia

Comment: Make sure you open the following books, just open each, and decide in some seconds if it fits the taste and the target. Chari & Pressley Guide to quantum groups, 1994, Kassel, Quantum Groups https://d-nb.info/941759644/04, Richard Kane, the Homology of Hopf Spaces, Sweedler - Hopf algebras, 1969, Christian Kassel, Quantum Groups, 1995. These are some sources that were helpful for me. My motivation is quite different, but each book has some ten - fifty pages, that give a possibility to "work and survive" computationally, to draw diagrams for a pictorial view, and have good structural examples.

Comment: Thanks, but a key phrase is "freely accessible pdf papers or books on the Web" for several good reasons.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115231/expository-papers-related-to-quantum-groups and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73261/hopf-algebras-and-quantum-groups/73278#73278  and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5682/what-are-the-uses-of-hopf-algebras-in-physics

Comment: Related "Introduction to representation theory" by
Pavel Etingof et al. https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0827

Comment: sorry, i was reading only the title which comes in bigger letters, the word "accessible" i then interpreted in a second as mathematically accessible. Only after the comment i realized that the text should be available by free download. In this case, maybe: http://preprints.ihes.fr/2006/M/M-06-40.pdf (IHES, Pierre Cartier, useful for application in homology theories, lambda operations, ... ) https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schweigert/ws12/hskript.pdf (plain university intro)

Comment: @dan_fulea, s'ok, I was able to peruse Kassel on Google books. Looks good.

Comment: @dan_fulea, thanks for a reminder on the Cartier paper. When I first perused it years ago, I was acquainted with very few of the topics he introduces. Since then I have encountered and played with many of them and am in a position to appreciate his presentation, which coincides with many of my interests now. For example, his perspective on formal group laws is very nice.

Comment: Also first chapter of Quantum Groups by C. De Concini in "D-modules, representation theory, and quantum groups: lectures given at the 2nd session of the Centro internazionale matematico estivo" with brief intro on relation to Lie theory.